# UrlRewrite, removing part of unmatched pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am kinda stumped here and could use some help. Transfering a bunch of pages from 1 server to another, and changing the path a bit to include the new user ID. I have the map completed of old urls to new ones, but my rewrite just isn't working.

Here is my current attempt at the htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule /users/MikeJones[^.*] http://new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

I would expect that any of these URL's, should all goto the URL I gave, not append part of the original URL on it.

My results are as follows:

```
old.com/users/MikeJones >  new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/ (Good!)
old.com/users/MikeJones/ >  new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones// (Bad)
old.com/users/MikeJones/test >  new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones//test (Bad)
old.com/users/MikeJones1234 >  new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/1234 (Bad)
old.com/users/MikeJones?test=that >  new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/?test=that (Bad)
```

I would like to always go to the same url, no matter what else was on the original url.

Like this:

```
old.com/users/MikeJones >  new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/ 
old.com/users/MikeJones/ > new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/
old.com/users/MikeJones/test > new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/
old.com/users/MikeJones1234 > new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/
old.com/users/MikeJones?test=that > new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your rule is working at all in your htaccess file because mod_rewrite strips off the leading `/` from the URI, so you'd need to match against `users/` and not `/users/`:

```
RewriteRule ^users/MikeJones http://new.com/profiles/1234/mikejones/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

should be all you need. You don't need any other rules, and if you *do* have other rules, make sure this one is *before* them.

Comment: Awesome, you are completely right. There was another rewrite system running, and only that was matching, which explains my troubles. Thanks!